Precise calculation of the integral $ \int \frac {1}{(x+1)\sqrt {x^2+2x-8}} dx $
I have this integral
$$ \int \frac {1}{(x+1)\sqrt {x^2+2x-8}} dx $$
I have solved it in two ways.

First, with a change of trigonometric variable

$$ x^2+2x-8 = (x+1)^2 -3^2 $$
$$ 3\sec{u} = x+1 \rightarrow 3\sec{u}\tan{u}\space du = dx $$
$$ \int \frac {1}{(x+1)\sqrt {x^2+2x-8}} dx = \int \frac {3\sec{u}\tan{u}}{3\sec{u} \sqrt{3^2 \sec^2{u}-3^2}}du =\frac{1}{3} \int \frac {\tan{u}}{\tan{u}} du  $$
$$ = \frac{u}{3}+k = \frac {1}{3} arcsec{ \frac {x+1}{3}}+k $$

Second, using Euler's substitution, which, in order not to write it out in full, I will leave out, but I put here the answer I arrived at

$$ \int \frac {1}{(x+1)\sqrt {x^2+2x-8}} dx = \frac {2}{3} \arctan{ \frac { \sqrt{x^2+2x-8}-x-1}{3}} +k  $$
Now, when I derive each of the answers to arrive at the original integrand with Mathematica, I get the following:

In other words, the integral calculated with the Euler substitution is more precise than the one calculated with the trigonometric substitution. I know that the first one is correct, but it is restricted to values of $ x+1 > 0 $

Because when $ x+1 < 0 $, there is a difference.

But I just realised that if I put absolute value, the difficulty is solved.

Now, my question is, how do I know that I should include absolute value in this type of problem.

Both the problem involves square-roots of negative numbers.  I guess that tells us that we should be considering this to be a complex variable problem.

Without trigonometric substitution
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \int \frac{1}{(x+1) \sqrt{x^2+2 x-8}} d x 
& =\int \frac{1}{(x+1)^2} d\left(\sqrt{x^2+2 x-8}\right) \\
& =\int \frac{d\left(\sqrt{x^2+2 x-8}\right)}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+2 x-8}\right)^2+9} \\
& =\frac{1}{3} \tan^{-1} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2 x-8}}{3}+C \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Wish it helps!

The reason why you need to include the absolute value is given below:
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{9\sec^{2}(u) - 9} = \sqrt{9\tan^{2}(u)} = 3|\tan(u)|
\end{align*}

Thank you, but what would be the procedure from there to the final result?

@EmersonVillafuerteJara Consider the cases $\tan(u)\geq 0$ and $\tan(u) < 0$ separately

You can still use the first method. Once you find any function that is antiderivative of the integrand you are done. For $x+1>3$ you have found one, of the form $f(x+1).$ For the interval $x+1<-3,$ which is disjoint with the first interval, take  $-f(-(x+1)).$
